# AngularJSにて、変数に$scopeを代入した際の質問

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

スコープの基礎的な指摘になるかもしれませんが、以下の事象が起きます。

```
app.controller("test", function($scope){
    var options = $scope.nav.getCurrentPage().options;
    $scope.item = options.item;  // {str:'test',int:'000000'}

    $scope.click = function() {
        var data = $scope.item;
        console.log($scope.item.int);  // 000000
        data.int = "123456";
        console.log($scope.item.int);  // 123456
```

以上のように、変数dataにバインドした$scopeを代入後、変数dataの値を変更した筈ですが、$scope自体の値も変わっています。
これは仕様なんでしょうか。
また、回避する手段はあるのでしょうか。
もしかしたらスコープの基礎的な部分かもしれませんが、分かる方が居ましたら回答お願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScriptにおいて、オブジェクトや配列を変数に代入すると参照渡しとなります。
`data`は最終的に`$scope.nav.getCurrentPage().options.item`を参照しているということです。

これを回避するには、`angular.copy()`を使用します。

```
var data = angular.copy($scope.item);
```

Comment: Javascriptにおける基礎知識だったようです。
angular.copy共々、勉強になりました。
また、希望通りの動きを確認しました。
ありがとうございます。